# The system cannot find the reference specified

Tags: vb.net

I've created project in VB 2019, was working ok. But due to some problem, I formated my PC & re-installed all the software. Now I realize that path of all the references I used in my project are missing and it shows "The system cannot find the reference specified".

Pls help how to resolve this issue.

Comment: which ones are they? do you need to reinstall them?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can just remove a reference and then re-add it from the appropriate location. You can do it all from the References page of the project properties or you can remove them in the Solution Explorer first. I'd suggest taking a screenshot first, so that you won't forget any.

Comment: Yes. I tried, but result is the same. I'm badly puzzled.